# angularjs: custom directive to check if a username exists- duplicate

Tags: html, angularjs

I have my registration form with textbox username. I want to do is when the user enter the username, the custom directive will check if the entered username is exists in the database.

So this is my api:

```
/*get the unique username*/
$app->get('/checkUsers', function ($id=null) {
$status_code = 200;
$resp = array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Query Success','data'=>null);
$resp['data'] = $id ?  User::find(username) : User::find_all_by_active('1'); 
    if(is_object($resp['data'])){
        $resp['data'] = $resp['data']->to_array();
     }else{
        $resp['data'] = objToArr($resp['data']);
     }
     JSONResponse($status_code,$resp);
 });
```

And this is my directives.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('installApp')
 .directive('ngUnique', function () {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {      

        // check that a valid api end point is provided
        if (typeof attrs.isUniqueApi === "undefined" || attrs.isUniqueApi === ""){
            throw new Error("Missing api end point; use is-unique-api to define the end point");
        }

        // set a watch on the value of the field
        scope.$watch(function () {
            return ctrl.$modelValue;
        }, function(currentValue) {

        // when the field value changes
        // send an xhr request to determine if the value is available
        var url = attrs.isUniqueApi;
            if (typeof currentValue !== 'undefined') {
                url += "?val=" + currentValue;
                elem.addClass('loading');
                $http.get('url').success(function(data) {
                    elem.removeClass('loading');
                    ctrl.$setValidity('unique', data.isAvailable);
                }).error(function() {
                    elem.removeClass('loading');
                });
            }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

And my view.html:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email" is-unique is-unique-api="../api/v1/checkUsers"/>
<p ng-show="newAccount.email.$dirty && newAccount.email.$invalid">
<span id="unique" ng-show="newAccount.email.$error.unique">Email already exists.</span>
</p>
```

So far I'm referring to this https://github.com/brunoscopelliti/ng-unique. But it didn't work for me, Please help! :'-( Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For this purpose asynchronous validators exist - see $asyncValidators property in ngModelController (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

```
ngModel.$asyncValidators.uniqueUsername = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
  var value = modelValue || viewValue;

  // Lookup user by username
  return $http.get('/api/users/' + value).
     then(function resolved() {
       //username exists, this means validation fails
       return $q.reject('exists');
     }, function rejected() {
       //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
       return true;
     });
};
```

Note, that this feature came in version 1.3.